# How to get index value from numberpicker in android

Tags: android, numberpicker

```
NumberPicker np;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             

            np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.np1);

            String[] values = {"one","two","three", "four","five","six","seven","eight"};       
            np.setMaxValue(values.length-1);
            np.setMinValue(0);
            np.setDisplayedValues(values);       
            np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
}
```

Above is a snippet of my code. So I am trying to get the index value of number picker that is selected. How do I write it? I already have something like this:

```
int pushupReps = Integer.parseInt(push_ups.getText().toString());
```

but it does not seem to be working and I have this in the OnCreate() method:

```
push_ups = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pushups);
```

This is my main xml used:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I&apos;m a Commando/Diver/Guards" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:text="Age: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/np1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:inputType= "none" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Push-ups: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pushups"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sit-ups: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/situps"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pushup_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="2.4km Run: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/run_minutes"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="mins" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/run_secs"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="secs" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="143dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Calculate" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="All Rights Reserved. Lee Guanhua 2014."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="8sp" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int pos = np.getValue()
```

should get the index.

```
values[pos]
```

gets you the value

Comment: got it thanks! Still, I need to make sure the other line is ok, can you check that?

Comment: what other line u mean ? From your other question?

Comment: This one:  int pushupReps = Integer.parseInt(push_ups.getText().toString());

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = np.getValue();
String selectedString = values[index]; // you will have the desired String from values array in selectedString
```